# How can I show facebook album images on my website using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

I created a site where I need to display the images from my facebook album to my personal website but when I call the `GetPhotoAlbum().Count` method then it returns a '0' count.

Any ideas why it says a zero count as I have 100's of public photos in my facebbok account?

Here is the code:

```
FriendList1.Friends = _fbService.GetFriends();
```

works fine and displays a list of all my friends list.

```
Response.Write(_fbService.GetPhotoAlbums().Count);
```

returns 0 and no photo/album is displayed

Comment: we'd rather not download your working project. Just post the relevant code in a code block.

Comment: @anuj - please edit your responses into the question, don't use the comments for this.

Comment: @bemused
@rockinthesixstring
question has been updated now with relevant code...please help me fix this.

Comment: Precisely which API are you using?

Comment: I am not sure about this but I can provide you the facebook.dll file if that is required?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get an access token with "user_photos" extended permission.  You can test this with the new Facebook [graph explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me/albums).

Comment: please can you confirm how to use this access token in the code?

Comment: I am able to get the records on the facebook graph site but the record count still says '0' when I try to use the getphotoalbumns() method. Do I have to define the access token somewhere in the code?